# iPhone4 taking picture from front camera

Tags: iphone, camera

I want to take a picture from the front camera from an iPhone4.
My problem is that the taken picture is mirrored after the shot.
So I thought to apply a mirror transformation on the preview in order to present the shot in the same way as the preview is.

This is the code that I use, but it doesn't work, the transformation don't mirror, it just rotate the picture, and I don't understand why it happens.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.cameraDevice=UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
imagePicker.cameraViewTransform=CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -1,1)
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
[imagePicker release];
```

What's wrong?

Thanks to all.

Comment: The same transformation works very well with the back camera on iPhone 3GS. So im starting to think it's a weird behaviour just of the front camera.

Comment: Just refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571445/edit-update-iphone-camera-showing-the-differnt-image-for-preview-and-uploading-di/7576155#7576155

Comment: this does not solve my problem, I want to transform the preview, not the final image.